# How reserve space for directory

Tags: linux, directory, filesystems

I have a 25GB disk partition mounted at /data . How can I reserve space, for example, 5GB for a specific directory, without creating an additional partition.

For example, I want to reserve 5 GB for `dir3`, 20 GB should remain for the rest of the data in / data.

```
/data 
|-dir1 
|-dir2 
|-dir3
```

I tried to do it through loopback, creating a file of the required size with `fallocate` and mounting, but this method does not reserve space, and after calling the `mkfs.ext4` command, the file does not take up disk space in the output of `df -h`.

Comment: A possibility on Linux is to learn how to use disk quotas. So other users won't be able to consume all the disk space

Comment: Please explain in your question why you want to do so, and what program or process requires disk space to be so "reserved". BTW, Linux has directories, not folders. Read about [inodes(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html) and [quotactl(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/quotactl.2.html)

Comment: @TheAct1on – Why do you think `fallocate` _does not reserve space_?

Comment: After calling `mkfs.ext4` new filesystem created and no files from previous filesystem exist. You should "reserve" space after mkfs.

Comment: @dimich `mkfs.ext4` was applied directly to the file created by `fallocate`, or should I not?

Comment: @Armali `fallocate` reserved space until I applied mkfs.ext4 to this file.

Comment: @TheAct1on, ah, i understand. You run mkfs on created file, not on device containing this file. `mkfs.ext4` punches holes in a file. Run `ftruncate` again after mkfs.

Comment: @dimich Thanks, it seems to help, but why exactly? To create a file system from a file, I need to call `mkfs`, but this behavior happens after this call) Will holes be punched again during operation, or can this be somehow avoided so that the reservation remains?

Comment: @TheAct1on You can run `mkfs.ext4` with `-E nodiscard` option. See [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104340/why-the-size-of-disk-image-decreased-after-mkfs-ext2) for details.

Comment: @dimich The `nodiscard` option punches holes anyway. When allocating 5G via `fallocate`, `du` displays 4.9G after `mkfs.ext4` :c

Comment: @TheAct1on I don't observe such behavior. `fallocate -l 5Gib image.bin && stat -c '%s %b' image.bin` gives me `5368709120 10485768`. `mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard image.bin && stat -c '%s %b' image.bin`: the same `5368709120 10485768`. Probably you're confused by gigabytes/gibibytes in `du` output.

Comment: @dimich Weird, I get the output of your commands first `5368709120 10485768` then `5368709120 10354576`. Number of used blocks decreased after `mkfs.ext4`.

Comment: @TheAct1on Indeed, that's weird. I observe block count reduction after `mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard` when file is created with `dd` but not with `fallocate`. `mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard` doesn't punch holes but block count reduced anyway. You can run `strace -f -yy -o mkfs.strace mkfs.ext4 ...` and check in `mkfs.strace` if it call `fallocate()` with `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` flag. Maybe it's a quirk of underlying filesystem driver where the file is stored. Maybe it detects "empty" writes in some cases and punches holes automatically.

Comment: @dimich If use `mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard -O ^has_journal image.bin && stat -c '%s %b' image.bin`, then there will be fewer missing blocks - `5368709120 10485640`. But 128 blocks are still missing.